Why is the hair not rendered in an animation?
Can anyone check my file?
The hair is visible in the viewport, it's also visible when I render only 1 frame but it's not rendered when rendering the animation...
I'm Using Blender 4.1.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jKZrEHIj-wlzETOKvnGQVZMm8NpWGwVV/view?usp=sharing
Thx!
Steven

it seems to work, maybe delete the cache and rebake? https://zupimages.net/up/24/21/wybj.gif

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Thanks for checking @moonboots ! Indeed it was a cache related issue... I forgot to clean / rebake the dynamic painting.

It's a problem of cache, delete the cache and rebake
